# Validate if a value is a whole number

Tags: javascript

I don't think isNaN is gonna work for my situation.  I want to make sure a certain variable only contains whole numbers when I validate it.  So -1.45 in my case should not be allowed.  Values such as 1, 23, 334 should be allowed/valid.

Comment: Whole numbers do not include negatives. So a complete answer would be `function isWholeNumber(v){return Number.isInteger(v) && v >= 0}`

Comment: I would argue that this question is not a duplicate because it's asking about whole numbers, not "float or integer".

Answer (score 26):

**PART #1:**

You can use [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operator to find if a value is whole number or not like:

```js
function isWholeNumber(value) {
  if (value % 1 === 0) {
    console.log(value + ' is a whole number');
  } else {
    console.log(value + ' is not a whole number');
  }
}

// Display the result here
isWholeNumber(1.45);
isWholeNumber(23);
```

**Explanation:**

- The remainder operator returns the remainder left over when one operand is divided by a second operand.
- For example, `1.45 % 1` returns `0.44999999999999996` and `23 % 1` returns `0`.
- So, now if a `value % 1 === 0`, then we can say that `value` is a whole number else not.

---

**PART #2:**

This logic fails in some cases where `value` is not actually a `number`, as [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operator (%) converts its operands to numbers like:

```js
function isWholeNumber(value) {
  console.log(value % 1); //<--- result is always 0
  if (value % 1 === 0) {
    console.log(value + ' is a whole number');
  } else {
    console.log(value + ' is not a whole number');
  }
}

// Display the result here
isWholeNumber('23');
isWholeNumber('');
isWholeNumber(true);
```

This result in a display of incorrect results like empty string and boolean value display as the whole number. We can fix this by checking of [type of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) value is `number` like:

```js
function isWholeNumber(value) {
  if (typeof value === 'number' && value % 1 === 0) {
    console.log(value + ' is a whole number');
  } else {
    console.log(value + ' is not a whole number');
  }
}

// Display the result here
isWholeNumber(1.45);
isWholeNumber(24);
isWholeNumber('23');
isWholeNumber('');
isWholeNumber(true);
```

---

**PART #3:**

In **ES6** global object `Number` got a new property [`Number.isInteger(value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger). It checks whether `value` is a whole number like:

```js
// Display the result here
console.log(Number.isInteger(1.45));
console.log(Number.isInteger(24));
console.log(Number.isInteger('23'));
console.log(Number.isInteger(''));
console.log(Number.isInteger(true));
```

We can integrate this with our *modified* `isWholeNumber` function in part #2 like:

```js
function isWholeNumber(value) {
  if (Number.isInteger(value)) {
    console.log(value + ' is a whole number');
  } else {
    console.log(value + ' is not a whole number');
  }
}

// Display the result here
isWholeNumber(1.45);
isWholeNumber(24);
isWholeNumber('23');
isWholeNumber('');
isWholeNumber(true);
```

Comment: These methods fail for large numbers such as `12345678901234567.5`

Answer (score 5):

`isNaN()` is to check number or not .It will not check the number is whole or not.

```
function isInt(n) {
   return n % 1 === 0;
}
```

or

```
if (number % 1 == 0) {
    alert('Whole Number');
} else {
    alert('Not a Whole Number');
}
```

Comment: Did you just copy-paste Palash's answer? Not very cool.

Comment: ...which was copied from the other answer.